# How can I set wallpapers for other users without logging in to their accounts?

Tags: shell-script, kali-linux, users, desktop, wallpaper

I am working on a bash script that creates users from the root account. I would like to set the background for those users without logging into their account and changing it manually. I am running Kali 4.19

I'm not sure if this is the way to do it, but I have tried:

`runuser user1 -c "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri /path/to/image/wallpaper.png"`

but I get the following error:

`(process:31838): dconf-CRITICAL **: 13:07:49.174: unable to create directory '/home/user1/.cache/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.`

What would be the best way to go about automating setting wallpapers for new users?

Comment: Kali is **NOT** a general purpose OS. If is for professional penetration testers. That even though they don't know the answer to this, will be able to find out in under a minute. Don't use it as a general purpose OS, and don't inflict it on others.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I am aware the use for Kali. My question still stands.

Comment: Then touch a time-stamp-file, change the wallpaper, and ask the OS to tell you all files in your `~`, that are newer than the time-stamp-file, and copy file to other users `~`.

Comment: I am looking more for the process to set the wallpaper of another user from the root account, rather than copying the file to their home directory.

Comment: Are you running `runuser` as root?  and show output of `findmnt -T /home/user1/.cache`